# How to pass new props after callback in react component?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I need to pass new props to child when callback was called in other child in this component. Here is a sample with `setState()`, which is doesn't work correctly. How i can do this? I.e bool value from `onChange` to `isExpanded`.

```
export default class Item extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        isExpanded: false,
    };

    this.handleChange = this.handleChange.bind(this);
}

render() {
    const {
        id,
        title,
    } = this.props;

    return (
        <ExpansionPanel onChange={this.handleChange}>
            <ExpansionPanelSummary expandIcon={<ExpandMoreIcon />}>
                <Typography>{title}</Typography>
            </ExpansionPanelSummary>

            <ExpansionPanelDetails>
                <Program isExpanded={this.state.isExpanded} id={id}/>
            </ExpansionPanelDetails>
        </ExpansionPanel>
    )
}

handleChange = (event, expanded) => {
    this.setState({isExpanded: expanded});
}
```

}

I expanded it, Program receive false: [console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5IRZt.png)

I closed it, Program receive true: [console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T8Gdg.png)

Comment: There's no setState in the code you posted. Please, provide https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve for your problem. You omitted the component while it's relevant.

Comment: I would also like to see more code and where you use setState but it sounds like you're trying to pass state from inside on child component to another. That means you're going to have to either prop drill or use some kind of state management. For something this simple you could probably just use context api but you could also use something like redux if you're going to be doing a lot of sharing of state through different components

Comment: @estus Sorry, I updated example, please check it

Comment: @MichaelCacciano please check updated example

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem was in `Program` component, which using `componentWillReceiveProps`.
I just used `newProps` and it works fine.
Here is working `componentWillReceiveProps` from `Program`:

```
componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps) {
    const {
        id,
        program,
        fetchData,
    } = this.props;

    console.log("isExpanded: ", nextProps.isExpanded)

    if(nextProps.isExpanded && !program[id]) {
        fetchData(id);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`onChange` doesn't provide `expanded` parameter and there's no need for it, because derived state should be set with [state updater function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#setstate) and current `isExpanded` value is available there:

```
handleChange = (event) => {
    this.setState(state => ({isExpanded: !state.isExpanded}));
}
```

Comment: But problem still here. When it handling change, it passing previous state to ```isExpanded```. I need to do it at the same time.

Comment: What exactly should be done at the same time? I assumed that you want to toggle `isExpanded` value. I'm not sure what the problem is and how it's supposed to work. Can you describe the behaviour you want and how it differs from current behaviour?

Comment: ok. When I expanding this panel, state is changing, but ```Program``` don't receive new props. Only when it handles second change, ```Program``` receive ```isExpanded``` with previous state.

Comment: How so? It clearly receives a prop, `<Program isExpanded={this.state.isExpanded} id={id}/>`. If it isn't updated for some reason, this may be specific to components in use, which aren't listed. Can you provide a demo that replicates the problem?

Comment: I added images to question. It should be true after expanding and false after closing. I can't write something like ```isExpanded={!this.state.isExpanded}```, because there ~50 same expansion panels, which shouldn't receive true at the start.

Comment: I don't think the issue can be solved without all components provided in the question. The problem is specific to your case and needs to be debugged.. Generally, it's very straightforward. When `state.isExpanded === false` and you do `this.setState(state => ({isExpanded: !state.isExpanded}))`, `<Program isExpanded={this.state.isExpanded} id={id}/>` should `true`. The rest is up to how components work.